# Make a Thread depend on isAlive() from another Thread

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, python-multithreading

I used the following python script https://github.com/fbjorn/QtWaitingSpinner to create a spinning circle on my PyQt5 GUI.

```
def initSpinner(self):
    self.spinner = spinner.WaitingSpinner(self)
    # Vorerst über show() hide() gelöst
    self.spinner.move(530, 30)
    self.spinner.start()
    self.spinner.hide()
```

My idea behind it is to have a spinning circle showed on the GUI while a thread is running. Now the Problem is when i call the `startThread` method my GUI is frozen until the Thread startet with `method` is finished.

```
def startThread(self, method):
    print(enumerate())
    if len(enumerate()) <= 20:
        t = Thread(target= method, daemon= True)
        t.start()
        sp = Thread(target= self.spinnerThread(t), daemon= True)
        sp.start()
    else:
        pass

def spinnerThread(self, thread):
    self.spinner.show()
    while thread.isAlive():
        pass
    self.spinner.hide()
```

If i outcommand the `sp` and i only start the `t` Thread my GUI is not frozen.

Comment: the GUI can be updated in a different thread than the main thread, so the tasks that involve the GUI within spinnerThread will not be executed, or they will do so with problems.

Comment: see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47359847/pyqt5-loading-spinner-halts-on-post-request